# Какой вариант лучше?

Tags: стилистика

С ужасом думал о предполагаемом прейскуранте местных таксистов, стоя в растерянности по центру неглубокой лужи и имея при этом вид мокрой курицы.        С ужасом думал о предполагаемом прейскуранте местных таксистов, стоя в растерянности по центру неглубокой лужи с видом мокрой курицы. *(Мне больше нравится второй, но сомнения в том, что читается, будто лужа, а не я - с видом мокрой курицы).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне не нравится сочетание "думать о предполагаемом", поскольку кто предполагает, тот и думает, сначала предположив. Но если уже предположил, то думать тут нечего - можно только ужасаться своему предположению. Предлагаемый вариант:

> Я (он) с ужасом строил догадки о прейскуранте местных таксистов,  стоя
>   в растерянности посреди неглубокой лужи подобно мокрой курице.

Answer (score 3):

С ужасом думал о предполагаемом прейскуранте местных таксистов, стоя по центру неглубокой лужи в растерянности, **с видом мокрой курицы**.

Answer (score 0):

А я бы перестроил фразу: 
С ужасом думал о предполагаемом прейскуранте местных таксистов, при этом стоя в растерянности, с видом мокрой курицы, по центру неглубокой лужи.

Comment: "С ужасом" + "с видом" в одном предложении - это некрасиво.

Comment: Можно заменить на "в ужасе"